# How are Data object variables available in mount hook in vue?

Tags: vuejs2

I have vue2 component where I want to access a data object variable to use in template. Pertinent code:
Template:

```html
<div v-html="theWivesBios[currentWife]" class="modal-content"></div>
```

Script:

```js
export default {
  name: "theSixWives",
  data() {
    return {
      theWivesBios: theWivesBios,
      currentWife: ""
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    elContainer.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
      //Want to manipulate this.currentWife in callback
      this.currentWife = "testing"; // this.currentWife isnt available to vue instance
    }
```

What would be best way to "hoist" this.currentWife so the vue instance would have access to it for use in my template?

Comment: Use an arrow function for your event handler, ie `elContainer.addEventListener("click", ev => { this.currentWife = "testing" })`

Comment: You can "store" this before .addEventListener like `const self = this;`. Inside listener function use `self.currentWife = 'testing';`. Arrow function is better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an arrow function like this:

```js
export default {
  name: "theSixWives",
  data() {
    return {
      theWivesBios,
      currentWife: ""
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    elContainer.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.currentWife = "testing";
    });
  }
}
```

This answer explains very well how `this` works on regular and arrow functions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/7699022

Hope it helped!

Comment: Yes thank you. So used to being told not to use arrow functions in Vue methods. I assume this works because this is now being taken from lexical scope?